# Auto-Update personal outlook contacts on GAL changes

Tags: exchange, microsoft-outlook-2013, contacts, auto-updates

I use Outlook where I have the Global Address List (GAL) online from an Exchange Server. Some of those contacts have been added to my personal contacts list in outlook. There are also some Lync contacts in my personal contacts, but in a different list.

When the details in the GAL of those contacts also in my personal contact list(s) are changed, I'd like the later to update, too.

The reason is, the Outlook Contacts including the ones from Lync are automatically synced to devices running iOS, Android or WP, but the GAL isn't. To make this clear, I don't want the full GAL copied to each users contacts folder and synced to each devices memory, just update the contacts already in there from the GAL.

To achieve this, the contacts have to be searched in the GAL by each user and then re-added to the personal contacts list.

How to do this? I prefer solutions where I don't need to buy other software.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, if you have **Outlook Social Connector** enabled, it updates your contacts from GAL automatically. To check this, open **View** tab on the ribbon, click **People Pane** button and select **Account Settings** there.

Comment: In the account settings, I see only SharePoint set up, so I suppose I have that Outlook Social Connector.
But still, the contact details don't get updated in outlook or my smartphone when I change them in the GAL. (I can see them changed when I open the GAL in outlook, but not in my personal contacts)

Comment: Download Outlook Social Connector 32-bit here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7985

Only works on Outlook 2003 and Outlook 2007 though. So, not an answer for Outlook 2013 users.